# Change colour of a menu option depend a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My application have a menu options and I need to change the color of a menu option depend of the selection of a textbox.

In the controller file I wrote this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Rise(int rise)
{
    Session["Var1"] = rise;
    if (rise != 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Var1= "class = active";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Var1 = "class = visited";
    }
    return View();
}
```

In my css file I wrote this:

```
a:visited
{
    font-size: large;  
    color: green;
}

a:active {
    font-size: large;  
    color: blue;
}

a:link  {
    font-size: large;  
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

And in my view I wrote this:

```
<li><a href="~/Home/Var1">Option1</a></li>
```

When I execute the application and I write a value in the textbox and click on the submit button I see that the menu option change the colour and change to Green colour again.

Comment: Can you explain clearly whats the issue and your expected output ?

Comment: check if you're getting the rise value in you controller or not (on debug mode)

Comment: and another question is that are you submitting a form to your controller? if so, please show us the form or the related part of it, or just a repro of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I need that the color will be persistent. My problem is that when I finish the click of the mouse the color back to the origin.